# Change webpage content?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I am new in the world of python, so I'm sorry.
I have a camera controlled by a python code.I want to count every person who pass the camera and show the number on a web page.
The object recognition algorithm and motion detection is working ok, but now I want to make a live preview on a webpage.
So in the `while(true)` from the python I want to call a function that changes the number of people that passed the camera on the web page without refreshing the webpage.
If anyone can give me a suggestion or a tutorial I will be grateful forever!

Comment: "without refreshing the webpage" do you mean using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, the only method i know is with Ajax...but i cant find out how to pass data from python to javascript...and javascript everytime is getting something from python to display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the number of passed people into a file accessible in webserver. You can retrieve this file by [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) embedded into your webpage.

Comment: Well...i tried to save it into a json...and then to read the json from javascript and show the number.But how do i know when the number is changed? I tried to make a loop to read the file on infinite, but the webpage has been blocked

Comment: @VladToma You can try to use websockets ( https://www.fullstackpython.com/websockets.html ) where a server can push data to the client.